# Google Wave gadget configure / set properties

Tags: python, google-wave

How can you configure or mutate a Google Wave gadget after creating one in Python? The following code will load the gadget via XML:

```
from waveapi import document
gadget = document.Gadget('http://domain.com/gadget.xml')
```

The [API reference](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/waveapi.document.Gadget-class.html) says you can pass a dictionary of initial properties, but I can't find any information on where the gadget would specify those initial properties. There are mentions of a getField/setField pair of methods to mutate gadget properties, but I can't find an API reference of them or again find where the gadget would specify these properties.

This came up because I am adding a Wave gadget as part of the response by a Wave robot, as described in the [Wave Extension FAQ](http://wave-api-faq.appspot.com/#robotgadget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gadget` is derived from `Element` which states:

> Although a Robot can query the properties of an element it can only interact with the specific types that the element represents.

The API does mention SubmitDelta() and get() , which seem like wrappers for setattr and getattr.

Discussion of (similar) issue [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-wave-api/browse_thread/thread/1716debed868eabf/b1f747a10c237cb0?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=setfield#b1f747a10c237cb0)